# "MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)" when i use floor database

Tags: database, flutter, sqflite, floor

I'm trying to use [floor](https://pub.dev/packages/floor) database but when i want to build database i got below **error** :

```
E/flutter (26007): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
E/flutter (26007): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
E/flutter (26007): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (26007): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter (26007): #2      invokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/sqflite_impl.dart:17:13)
E/flutter (26007): #3      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.invokeMethod (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:82:7)
E/flutter (26007): #4      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.safeInvokeMethod.<anonymous closure> (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:25:35)
E/flutter (26007): #5      wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/exception_impl.dart:7:32)
E/flutter (26007): #6      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl.wrapDatabaseException (package:sqflite/src/factory_impl.dart:78:7)
E/flutter (26007): #7      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.safeInvokeMethod (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:25:7)
E/flutter (26007): #8      SqfliteDatabaseFactoryMixin.getDatabasesPath (package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart:143:26)
E/flutter (26007): #9      getDatabasesPath (package:sqflite/sqflite.dart:168:54)
E/flutter (26007): #10     DatabaseFactoryExtension.getDatabasePath (package:floor/src/sqflite_database_factory.dart:23:23)
E/flutter (26007): #11     _$AppDatabaseBuilder.build (package:fluttermiwallet/db/database.g.dart:46:40)
E/flutter (26007): #12     main (package:fluttermiwallet/main.dart:9:67)
E/flutter (26007): #13     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:241:25)
E/flutter (26007): #14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter (26007): #15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter (26007): #16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1619:10)
E/flutter (26007): #17     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1608:12)
E/flutter (26007): #18     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:5)
E/flutter (26007): #19     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
E/flutter (26007): #20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

**my flutter version:**

```
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (13 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4
```

**the version of floor,floor_generator and build_runner are as below :**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  floor: ^0.13.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  floor_generator: ^0.13.0
  build_runner: ^1.7.3
```

in the **main.dart** i build my database using $FloorAppDatabase :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  var db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('mydb.db').build();
  runApp(MyApp(db));
}
```

and in the android folder **GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java**:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import androidx.annotation.Keep;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimPluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
 * plugins that support the Android platform.
 */
@Keep
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);
      io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin.registerWith(shimPluginRegistry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.FlutterAndroidLifecyclePlugin"));
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
    flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
  }
}
```

and **MainActivity.kt**:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(
                registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"))

    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found my answer. **I must add Sqflite plugin in my MainActivity: `SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"))`**

my MainActivity changed as below:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin


class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(
                registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerPlugin"))
        SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"))

    }

}
```

Comment: this now throws error :  `Unresolved reference: registrarFor`. how do one resolve this?

Answer (score 33):

This happen due to the newly added dependencies, where in my case the following command worked.
Go to the terminal and then

```
flutter clean
```

And re run the project

Comment: This is solved my same problem <3

Comment: This solved my problem as well

Answer (score 13):

Silly me, I ran into this error when trying to run my sqflite app in Chrome. Of course [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) does not support web, so I shouldn't be surprised it's throwing an error! Running in a mobile emulator (or macos) should work.

Answer (score 10):

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you are facing this only on release build then build your release app with proguard rules

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Create a file on the directory `android/app/` name the file as `proguard-rules.pro` and write inside:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me! Thanks! You've just saved my day. Though I still don't really understand why it works...

Comment: Built-in code shrinker on Gradle obfuscate some classes and remove some dead code. Built-in code shrinker removes third party plugin's classes also. For that reason we had to add proguard-rules for prevent obfuscate of our third party plugin's classes.

Comment: You just made my day :) I had the same issue and this fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using HotReload / Run, stop the application and start again.

Answer (score 3):

I would try several things:

- first ensure that all plugins are indeed registered by trying for example to use SharedPreferences instead of sqflite
- Follow the plugin migration guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/plugin-api-migration if your app was not created recently
- Try to remove the ImagePickerPlugin registration in onCreate (or basically get rid of the onCreate in your MainActivity).
- Try to delete the android folder and create the project again

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have done below steps to make it work:

- Create Application class (if not already created) for android in the same package where you have MainActivity.

MyApp.kt

```
package com.example.flutter_example

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin

class MyApp : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry) {
        com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin.registerWith(
                registry.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"))
    }
}
```

- Now update your Android manifest file and provide your Application class.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
```

- Now clean and run the project.

Answer (score 2):

when you run project on chrome, it's normal that the program show an error because sqflite doesn't support on chrome, just re run the project on android/iOs and the error will disappear.

Comment: Needs more clarity

Answer (score 1):

This happended even to me a,just stop the app and rebuild it and it may work as it means that the dependencies are not present.If even that doesn't work ,then "flutter clean" will do  your job

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on `Flutter Windows` and solved by following the docs.

`flutter pub add sqflite_common_ffi`

[image]

Linux/Windows users:
https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi

```
Future<Database>? getDb() {
    _db ??= _initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  // Guaranteed to be called only once.
  Future<Database> _initDb() async {
    Database db;

    if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
      sqfliteFfiInit();
      var databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
      db = await databaseFactory.openDatabase(inMemoryDatabasePath);
    } else {
      var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      final path = '${databasesPath}my_database.db';
      db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
      );
    }
    return db;
  }
```