# build apk does't work, but debug apk works as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, apk, sqflite

My build apk doesn't work as expected. but debug apk works perfectly. when i run *flutter run --release -v* it shows:-

- MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)
- Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method pickImage on channel plugins.flutter.io/image_picker)

How can i solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/62929583/8380779`

Comment: yes i tried this. it shows another error : Unresolved reference: registrarFor

Comment: have you tried this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53992118/unresolved-reference-android-on-new-flutter-project` or `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965783/flutter-plugin-development-unresolved-reference-io/56974312`?
Basically, rebuild the project or invalidate cache and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by downgrading buld.gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0

Answer (score 0):

This probably related with current issue in flutter (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65334) where `DefaultLifecycleObserver` got removed by proguard. See explanation:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58479#issuecomment-763259817

The solution is by adding the line below to your android `app/proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
```